# Angular2: How change pristine of NgModel in code?

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

When you change the field of NgModel, it automatically change model.prisitne to true.

When you submit the form, it does't change the "pristine", no question, this is not a bug.

But in my case, I show errors when "pristine" is true and when I submit the form, I need to show validation errors and I think when you submit the form, we can say that the fields in this form touched, because you can't submit the invalid form. But in Angular2 it works in different way.

So, any way to say that the form controls/fields is touched (pristine = true) in code/component?

```
let email:AbstractControl = this.frm.form.controls['email'];
```

Set email "prisitne" true.

Comment: In what code? Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: I add a code line.

Comment: I think you have some wrong understanding about pristine and touched. 1) both are not same.2) When you change input value,  pristine becomes false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
email.markAsPristine();
email.markAsTouched();
email.reset();
```

or

```
this.frm.reset();
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html

You can use this shorter method to get a control

```
let email:AbstractControl = this.frm.get('email']);
```

Answer (score 5):

every form control has its different states attached.

you can check any state through following code,

```
this.frm.form.controls['email'].pristine;
this.frm.form.controls['email'].touched;
```

For reference. check out this plunker and click on button.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mJFftirG3ATDpnJRWmKN?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As of Angular v4.4.5

**`markAsDirty()`** removes the control pristine state

**`markAsPristine()`** sets the control to pristine state