# Angular Forms - why and when we are using markAsPristine() function?

Tags: angular4-forms

I need to get the better understanding of the use of `markAsPristine()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: How change pristine of NgModel in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014626/angular2-how-change-pristine-of-ngmodel-in-code)

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014905/2605758)